# Does Earth Science cover the practical aspects of combatting climate change?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I recently went searching through the Stack Exchange site list for one that may support practical advice for combating climate change on every level: personal, business, local, state or nationally.

I noticed that you have a [climate-change](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) tag, and went through the [tour](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour), [help page](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and meta, but none quite answer my question. Does Earth Science support questions such as:

- *How much are carbon emissions reduced if a diesel bus is switched out for electric?*
- *Which types of trees are the best to plant for offsetting emissions?*
- *What technologies exist to reduce evaporation of a dam water source?*
- *What is the average ROI period for installing rooftop solar?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that for those questions, you will get better answers if you ask them on [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

If I were reviewing, I think I'd consider questions 2 and 3 on-topic. That doesn't necessarily mean that this is the best place to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

I consider questions about emissions and evaporation to be fine for Earth Science ... but you should look at Engineering Stack Exchange if you are interested in technology like renewable energy.  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/
The anthropogenic climate change problem, at this point, is purely a political and social problem.  All the technology already exists to stop carbon pollution from being a global environmental issue.  So, "combatting climate change" isn't really an Earth Science topic in my opinion.